# Split data in multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table as below

[image: Data]

I want it to be split in multiple rows to show data as one player with country in single row.

[image: Output]

Is there a formula in excel which will help me get to the output.

I tried filter function but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(B2:D6<>"",A2:A6),2),TOCOL(B2:D6,1))
```

---